# How to not have Show Table Dialog for new Access query

Tags: microsoft-access

In Access when I go `Create > Query Design` it creates a new query window and automatically pops open the `Show Table` dialog. I don't like to use this and instinctively hit `esc`. I either go straight into SQL view or drag and drop my tables from the Navigation Pane.

How can I not show this pop up when I create a new query?

Answer (score 1):

If you find Show table sufficiently annoying, you might try this (it works in 2007).  It's a kludge, but opens a query in SQL View.

Use the usual steps to get into query design, close the table dialog, then go to SQL view.  Enter the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table];
```

Save as `_qryTemplate`.

From Navigation you can then right click on `_qryTemplate`, select Design View and VOILA: you're in SQL view.

Yeah, I know, it's ugly, but Access is not generally known for its beauty.

Comment: A good idea but not quite what I'm looking for.